# AES Encryption In .Net And Decryption In Node JS

Tags: c#, node.js, .net, encryption, cryptojs

I have a simple node js code with crypto js library through which I am decrypting a json object which I will receive from a .net based desktop application, hence the whole process is cross-platform. For testing I can easily encrypt using crypto js library and decrypt the cipher text generated by it. But my doubt is if this method is going to be compatible with encryption in .net. As I'm new to this, so far what I've learned is that the crypto js library generates a random Integration vector (IV) value. If an IV is generated by the .net code as well, do I need to specify it during decryption in node js as well? Currently I'm just using the simple example given in the documentation and no IV or padding is specified and I'm not sure if any default specifications are used by this library. In short I just need to make sure I'm doing this correctly and the method used for decryption won't cause any issues for the encryption part.

```
var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");

var aeskey = "bQeThWmZq4t7w!z%C*F-JaNcRfUjXn2r";
var cloudcreds = {
  accessKeyId: "abcdef",
  accessKeySecret: "zxywvt",
};

//Encryption - Tbd with .net
var encryptedData = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(
  JSON.stringify(cloudcreds),
  aeskey
).toString();
console.log("Encrypted Cloud Creds =>", encryptedData);

//Decryption - With node js
var bytes = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encryptedData, aeskey);
var decryptedData = JSON.parse(bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
console.log("Decrypted Cloud Creds => ", decryptedData);
```

Comment: Since a decryption is always tailored to the encryption, you should also post the .NET code that performs the encryption. The IV (16 bytes for AES) used in the encryption is needed for the decryption. Usually a random IV is generated during the encryption, which is binary concatenated with the ciphertext typically in the order IV | ciphertext. Since the IV is no secret, it does not need to be encrypted. The result is sent to the receiver, who can separate both parts and perform the decryption.

Comment: Concerning CryptoJS you have to keep in mind that the key has to be passed as `WordArray`, otherwise it will be interpreted as password, from which the actual key (32 bytes) and IV are derived, like in your posted example code. Probably this does not happen on the .NET side, so you should not use this key derivation, which you can achieve by passing the key and IV as `WordArray`. But as I said, that depends on the encryption you didn't post.

Comment: Actually the .net code is still a couple of months behind so decryption part with node js is to be completed first. I'm starting to grasp these concepts but not completely. Do you think I should use the built in crypto library in node instead of crypto-js and statically pass the IV? Will that solve the problem of IV being randomly assigned?

Comment: No matter whether you start with encryption or decryption, both sides have to fit together in the end. Which library you use depends on the requirements, but AES/CBC/PKCS7 (as in your CryptoJS code) can handle any modern symmetric library. And why not use the crypto module of NodeJS if you are in a NodeJS environment anyway? Concerning the IVs there is a simple rule: A key/IV pair may only be used once. Check if your design meets this rule. Usually, to prevent multiple use (with the same key), a new random IV is generated for each encryption.

Comment: Does that mean if cryptoJs encryption assigns an IV randomly, then it will simply be impossible to decrypt the data if some other means is used to encrypt the data even if the key is same i.e .net?

Comment: If you refer to your posted CryptoJS code: Your key `bQeT...` is not interpreted as a key but as a password, from which the actual key and IV are derived using a proprietary (non standard and relatively weak) openssl algorithm in combination with a randomly generated salt. To make decryption possible in a different environment, you need exactly this algorithm for decryption (which is oob generally not available), so that key and IV can be reconstructed (from password and salt). Although there are C# implementations on the net, I would advise against it because of the obvious disadvantages.

Comment: The crypto module could work fine it seems. Let me know what you think, I've posted an answer.

Comment: I will receive randomly generated key + IV from .net app. These values will itself be encrypted with RSA.

Answer (score 1):

With the crypto module I'm now using my own IV and so far it seems like this could work.

```
var crypto = require("crypto");

var algorithm = "aes-256-cbc"; //algorithm to use
const key = "3zTvzr3p67VC61jmV54rIYu1545x4TlY"; //create key
var data = {
  name: "Catalin",
  surname: "Munteanu",
  address: "Romania",
};
data = JSON.stringify(data);
const iv = "0000000000000000"; // generate different ciphertext everytime

const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, key, iv);
var encrypted = cipher.update(data, "utf8", "base64") + cipher.final("base64"); // encrypted text
console.log(encrypted);

const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(algorithm, key, iv);
var decrypted = decipher.update(encrypted, "base64", "utf8") + decipher.final("utf8"); //deciphered text
console.log(JSON.parse(decrypted));
```

Comment: What is still missing is the random IV generation, concatenation and separation of IV and ciphertext to avoid that key / IV pairs are used multiple times.

Comment: Yeah I guess I will just receive randomly generated Key and IV from .net application, so I can use accordingly in the node js middleware.